# Recalculate unique rank with autofilter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Because I have a lot of items that rank at 1 (or 100%), I'm using this formula to get a unique rank as you can see in the image below under "Filtered Unique Rank":

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$1000)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1
```

This was my old Rank formula under "Regular Rank", which essentially showed a lot of items ranking at 1:

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$1000)
```

[image]

This is the formula I was using to get rankings based on a filter, but it's NOT unique:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A$2:$A$1000,ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$1000)),0,1)),--(A2<$A$2:$A$1000))+1
```

**Question:** Based on the info above, is there a way to get a unique rank from an autofilter? 
Source of above formula: http://www.mrexcel.com/td0067.html

Comment: It is possible, but you would need **two** helper columns....is this acceptable??

Comment: I would love to see an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the data is like:

[image: unfiltered]

Column **B** is filled with the formula for the "standard" unique, sequential rank, so **B2** contains:

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$10)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1
```

In **D2** we enter:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,$B2:$B2)=0,"",A2)
```

and copy down.  The helper **D** column resembles column **A** except if the row is hidden, the value is a blank.  In **E2** we enter:

```
=RANK(D2,$D$2:$D$10)+COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2)-1
```

and copy down.

Here is a snap with the filter applied:

[image: filterapplied]

Note column **E** produces a simple, unique, sequential rank.

Comment: This works! However, I don't understand the formula in D2. Thanks btw

Comment: @XtremeHavoc:  If row#2 is hidden, the formula in **D2** gives a blank, otherwise it gives the value in **A2.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this **array formula****:

=INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A$2,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$10)),,,)),$A$2:$A$10),A2),2)+INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A$2,ROW($A$2:A2)-MIN(ROW($A$2:A2)),,,)),$A$2:A2),A2-{0.00001,0}),2)

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thanks XOR LX, but for some odd reason, I was getting different ranks. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/oCiZ3wq.jpg. There's only 757 items in that list. All the formulas were adjusted to look at 1000 lines.

Comment: Unfortunately that screenshot doesn't tell me the ranges involved, nor the precise formula(s) you entered, and in which cells you entered them. Also, I assume you understood the instructions re array formulas?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was running late and posted a quick screenshot. I'll check this further and post more details.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the values passed to formula by using autofilter. The formula will still refer to the same count and values, whether they appear hidden or not.

However, you can achieve this by using **pivot table filters** as they render the content of cells by changing their values.

Comment: This formula got me recalculated ranks based on filter, just not unique ranks: =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A$2:$A$1000,ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$1000)),0,1)),--(A2<$A$2:$A$1000))+1